# SQL 2014 Availability Group Cluster or Listener

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, failover, listener

We recently deployed a setup of `SQL 2014 availability groups` and we are having some difficulty with the failover.

**Setup:**

- Two windows server 2012R2 VMs in a windows cluster with a CNAME pointed at the cluster IP address.
- The availability group is setup synchronously.
- The listener and the CNO are both in active directory.
- The application is using the cluster CNAME to connect to the database.

The problem we are running into is that in the event of a failover the Windows cluster is failing over, and the AG is not.  So we get the primary of the windows cluster pointed at the secondary of the AG, so all the databases are read only.

**My question is:**

> should we be pointing the CNAME at the listener instead of the Cluster
>   IP?  Or more generally what is the proper way to ensure correct
>   failover behavior?

Comment: Need more info ...Have you configured the dependency of the listener as `OR` in the cluster ? What is the output of `sys.availability_group_listeners` ? Do you have a fileshare witness configured ?

Comment: Yes we have a fileshare witness, there is only one listener, and I don't know what you mean by the dependency of the listener as OR in the cluster.

Comment: You can configure the listener dependency in the cluster properties --> Dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that yes the cname should be pointed at the listener IP.